# Aircraft trajectory prediction

Tags: physics, mathematics, trajectory, motion, extrapolation

I have an aircraft that is controlled by player and i need to predict it's position at needed time. It's not a problem if the plane is just moving straight but most of the time aircraft is maneuring. So i came up with an aproximation that aircraft movement can be described as a helix.

[image]

So i have a point A and linear velocity V_1 that aircraft had at a time of t_1. Point B and linear velocity V_2 that aircraft had at a time of t_2. In that approximation we may assume that |V_1| equals |V_2| so it will be a perfect helix. And i need to find a point C in that aircraft will be at a time of t_3.

Comment: have you tried to take an integral of velocity over time to get displacement function of time?

Comment: @Ocelot hm, but how do i take an integral of velocity if i don't know the formula of how velocity is changed over time?

Comment: you can derive the formula from what you already use in your game, if you need help with that, include in your question how you currently calculate velocity. For helix specifically, displacement function of time is `(r*cos(t), r*sin(t), t)`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix#Mathematical_description you can try to plot different variations of it using GeoGebra 3D and see which one satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @Ocelot im using an asset that controls the movement, so i don't know exact formula for velocity. I could use that formula from wikipedia but i have to know the direction of where the helix goes. Like at my picture (and for wiki formula) the helix goes to the negative Z (0, 0, -1) but in reality it can goes at any direction. If i would know the direction then a could just unrotate the positions and velocities to the standart (0, 0, -1), calculate new position and rotate it back.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but `(r*cos(t), r*sin(t), vt)` goes to the positive Z, given that `v` is a positive value. And you can change the direction of helix rotation by negating X component in the formula. Other than that, I'm afraid I can't provide any more help if you don't have the necessary information in regards to the inner workings of your project.

Comment: @Ocelot I mean that helix won't be always built around Z-axis. https://imgur.com/a/w6UUsTp the dir is a direction of what helix is built. The formula (r*cos(t), r*sin(t), vt) could be applied only of the helix is built around Z axis. So i need to find that dir vector, rotate the positions to the inverse of dir, apply the formula, and rotate it back to the dir. The problem is i don't know how to find dir based on previous positions and velocities.

Comment: Direction based on two positions is `normalize(pos-prev_pos)`, but it's one frame behind. You can't predict the future exactly if you don't know the formula of the aircraft motion.